# Resources array in full calendar scheduler are not populating in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using full calendar scheduler (1.6.2) and i am retrieving the resources from some drop down and creating the array and feed to full calendar scheduler. Resources are successfully added in firefox but in IE 11 only the last selected dropdown is added,below is my code.what am i missing or is there any bug in full calendar.

```
$("#schedule_employees > option:selected").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $(this).text();
    item = {}
    item.id = id;
    item.title = title;
    employees.push(item);
    employee2 = employee2 + $(this).attr('id') + ",";
});

if (employees.length == 0) {
    alert("Please select the employees");
    return false;
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio: '1',
    height: "auto",
    scrollTime: '00:00',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'Schedule,agendaDays'
    },
    groupByResource: "true",
    defaultView: 'Schedule',
    titleRangeSeparator: ' - ',
    allDaySlot: false,
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    views: {
        agendaDays: {
            type: 'agenda',
            slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
            //groupByDateAndResource: true,
            groupByResource: true,
            buttonText: 'Agenda 2 days',
            duration: {
                days: 2
            },
        },
        Schedule: {
            type: 'timeline',
            slotDuration: '04:00:00',
            slotLabelInterval: {
                hours: 4
            },
            buttonText: 'Schedule',
            visibleRange: {
                start: moment($("#start_Date input").val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                end: moment($("#end_Date input").val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        }
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Employees',
    resourceAreaWidth: '25%',
    resources: employees,
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        renderScheduleReport(employee2);
    },
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Comment: any console errors in IE?

Comment: @ADyson no error as such , also only the last selected dropdown is added as a resource in IE 11 but not all the selected ones,why ?

Comment: can we see the HTML for the dropdowns please? Does the jQuery selector just pick up the last one, is that the reason? Have you stepped through the code to see if that's where the problem is?

Comment: @ADyson yes its working perfect in firefox but not in IE , i have debug in IE and found that employees variable does contain the all the options selected from the dropdown

Comment: ok so please show the related HTML as I requested, also the code is incomplete - you don't show how employees or employee2 are first declared

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your time ,i have resolved please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

after hours of debugging i have found what's going wrong.In the below loop employees array contains the same element for each iteration ,replacing the existing one so in the end variable contains the same elements.Don't know why IE always causing trouble.

```
$("#schedule_employees > option:selected").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $(this).text();
```

change the below line from

> ```
>     item = {} //this is causing issue
> ```

to

> `var item = {};`

```
    item.id = id;
    item.title = title;
    employees.push(item);
    employee2 = employee2 + $(this).attr('id') + ",";
});
```