# while using fullcalendar scheduler i'm not able to see any resources only events i'm able to see

Tags: angular, fullcalendar-scheduler

this is Js file
while running in browser its showing Cannot set property 'scheduler Version' of undefined
FC.schedulerVersion = "1.6.2";

Comment: Please edit your question and try to add a few details. At first, your javascript code is missing. You give no information about plugin version and browser version.

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730849/resources-array-in-full-calendar-scheduler-are-not-populating-in-ie-11): same topic, but the question provides details information about the usage scenario.

Comment: I have used plugin version as 1.6.2 for full calendar-scheduler and browser version is 60.0.3112.90

Comment: And your `js` code?

Comment: edited my js code

Comment: Why did you remove your code alltogether?